# deadlocking when multple user execute SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock

we have a stored procedure that are  inserting/updateing/deleteing Item resource files and we have a problem where the user some times getting deadlocked and i belive is becuase the stored procedure is in use by another user.
[image: deadlocking]

SP

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [file].[usp_iudItemResourceFile]
    @p_ItemID INT
    , @p_ID INT = NULL OUTPUT
    , @p_IsDefault BIT = NULL
    , @p_Description NVARCHAR ( MAX ) = NULL

    --, @p_RelPath NVARCHAR ( 2000 ) = NULL
    , @p_Name NVARCHAR ( 250 ) = NULL
    , @p_sequenceNumberID INT = NULL
    , @p_Type TINYINT = NULL
    , @p_Size INT = NULL
    , @p_Status TINYINT = NULL
    , @p_DoerTicket VARCHAR ( 200 ) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @doerUserID INT
            , @doerCompanyID INT
    EXEC system.usp_validateAuthenticationTicket @p_Ticket = @p_DoerTicket
                                                , @p_UserID = @doerUserID OUTPUT
                                                , @p_CompanyID = @doerCompanyID OUTPUT


    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF ( @p_ID < 0 )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'TBD'
    END

    DECLARE @res INT
    EXEC @res = [file].usp_iudResourceFile @p_ID = @p_ID OUTPUT
                                    --, @p_RelPath = @p_RelPath
                                    , @p_Name = @p_Name
                                    , @p_Type = @p_Type
                                    , @p_Size = @p_Size
                                    , @p_Status = @p_Status
                                    , @p_DoerTicket = @p_DoerTicket

    IF ( ( @@ERROR <> 0 ) OR ( @res <> 0 ) )    
    BEGIN
        IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN 1050
    END

    IF ( ( @p_ID > 0 ) AND ( @p_IsDefault = 1 ) )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [file].ItemResourceFile SET
            IsDefault = 0
        WHERE Item_ID = @p_ItemID

        IF ( @@ERROR <> 0 ) 
        BEGIN
            IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN 1053
        END
    END

    MERGE INTO [file].ItemResourceFile AS target
    USING ( SELECT @p_ItemID
                    , @p_ID
                    , @p_IsDefault
                    , @p_Description
                    , @p_Status
                    , @p_sequenceNumberID
                    , @doerUserID
                    , @doerCompanyID ) AS source ( ItemID, ResourceFileID, IsDefault, Description, Status, sequenceID, DoerUserID, DoerCompanyID )
        ON ( target.Item_ID = source.ItemID )
            AND ( target.ResourceFile_ID = source.ResourceFileID )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                target.Description = NULLIF ( ISNULL ( source.Description, target.Description ), N'' )
                , target.IsDefault = ISNULL ( source.IsDefault, target.IsDefault )
                , target.Status = ISNULL ( source.Status, target.Status )
                , target.sequenceID = source.sequenceID
                , target.LastModifierUser_ID = source.DoerUserID
                , target.DateTimeModified = GETUTCDATE ( )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND source.ResourceFileID > 0 THEN
            INSERT ( Item_ID
                    , ResourceFile_ID
                    , Description
                    , IsDefault
                    , Status
                    , sequenceID
                    , CreatorUser_ID
                    , LastModifierUser_ID )
                VALUES ( source.ItemID
                        , source.ResourceFileID
                        , NULLIF ( source.Description, N'' )
                        , ISNULL ( source.IsDefault, 0 )
                        , ISNULL ( source.Status, 0 ) --0: Active
                        , source.sequenceID
                        , source.DoerUserID
                        , source.DoerUserID
                        )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
                AND target.Item_ID = @p_ItemID
                AND target.ResourceFile_ID = ABS ( @p_ID ) THEN
            DELETE;

    IF ( @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 )
    BEGIN
        IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ( 'DBException_ItemNotFound', 16, 1 )
        RETURN 1060
    END

    --IF ( @p_ID IS NULL )
    --  SET @p_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY ( )

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN 0
END
```

how do i fix it so it can be used by multiple user or find out what there are realy triggering it

Comment: Try looking at Activity Monitor to see the resources involved in the deadlock. Typicaly a deadlock will happen when one process acquires a lock on resource A and another process acquires a lock on resource B. Then the first process tries to acquire a lock on B so it must wait, but the other process is trying to acquire a lock on A so it waits too. SQL Server detects this and kill one of the two processes to resolve the deadlock.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/) first, so you'll have the details about the deadlock to investigate.

Comment: is actualy not something that are in the activity monitor as is only running when the user execute from an external program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SP basicly does this:

1. UPDATE Table
2. SELECT FROM Table
3. UPDATE Table or INSERT Table

All happening in the same transaction (where 2+3 = MERGE)

A deadlock situation can happen when two instances simultaneously runs statement 1. Neither instance can then execute statement 2 because some rows in the table is locked by the update in the other instance.

The way to avoid deadlocks on one table with multiple updates is to ensure different instances does not try to read rows which can be locked by other instances. A common error is to cause table scans by using non-indexed columns in the WHERE clause or aggregates (e.g. MAX).

This query can give you (somewhat cryptic) details on where your deadlock happens

```
WITH XmlData AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(xml, [target_data]) AS Target_Data
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xt
         INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xs
             ON xs.address = xt.event_session_address
    WHERE xs.name = N'system_health'
          AND xt.target_name = N'ring_buffer'
)
SELECT xed.value('@timestamp', 'datetime') as Creation_Date,
       xed.query('.') AS Extend_Event
FROM XmlData 
     CROSS APPLY Target_Data.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData(xed)
ORDER BY Creation_Date DESC
```

Comment: +1 for that now i can see a more detailed view of it and all the other deadlocks that had happend
 but are there away to export it to a graph